# Reset save filename

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

After enabling `Always ask you where to save files` for downloading, how to reset filename when accidentally modified?

I tried:

- usual undo shortcut (`ctrl`+`z`), no effect
- right click (only has cut, copy, paste, delete, select all, insert emoji), no "undo"

For example, if you `ctrl`+`s` this page, the default name is `firefox - Reset save filename - Super User.html` AND `firefox - Reset save filename - Super User` is selected by default.

I sometimes accidentally type backspace and only `.html` remains.

How can I reset back to original filename without `ctrl`+`s` again OR make it so the default selection is nothing? (because I sometimes use right click --> save link as so it's harder than just `ctrl`+`s`)

Sometimes download sites require waiting 30 seconds before being able to start a download once and then the link expires (need to wait 30 secs to generate another).

Comment: `CTRL+S` again I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 or what operating system? If I `Ctrl` + `S` this page, hit backspace, I am still able to undo once with `Ctrl` + `Z` and get `firefox - Reset save filename - Super User` back. If I type something then the last step gets lost and I can only undo once.

Comment: @MC10 I'm on Ubuntu with default window manager. I cannot get even one `Ctrl` + `Z` to undo. It does nothing at all.